# Delete characters between other

Tags: java, regex

I have one String with a lot of sentences and this string has words like "ga- te", "ga - te" etc. 
I need to convert all words like "ga- te" to "gate" and don't touch each other. I tried to use regexp but it's unsuccessfully. Can you help me with it?
P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What are the regexes/code you tried? This is pretty simple. Some hints: `\s` will match a whitespace, `*` is a quantifier which will match the previous token zero or more times.

Comment: Provide line of code, it will be easy to understand..

Comment: Tried "[a-z]- [a-z]" but after that i understand that can't delete only "- " because i use replaceAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place [capturing groups](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) around what you want to retain and refer those groups in the replacement call.

```
String s = "ga- te, ga - te, foo  - bar";
s = s.replaceAll("([a-z]) *- *([a-z])", "$1$2");
System.out.println(s); //=> "gate, gate, foobar"
```

Comment: Thanks, all work but i will use ("([a-z])- *([a-z])", "$1$2") because only "ga- te" is interesting for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.replaceAll(String,string)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and something like

```
String[] arr = { "ga- te", "ga - te" };
for (String str : arr) {
    String word = str.replaceAll("\\s*-\\s*", "");
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Output is

```
gate
gate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "ga - te"
s = s.replaceAll("(?=[a-zA-Z]) *- *(?=[a-zA-Z])", "");
```

Just look positive lookaheads to check that there is a letter before and after without matching it.

Comment: it would be `"(?<=[a-zA-Z]) *- *(?=[a-zA-Z])"`